# pip install futures breaks pip, but only on amazonlinux?

Tags: python, pip, amazon-linux

This probably falls under "don't do this" category, given https://github.com/agronholm/pythonfutures/issues/41 - it's a backport library specifically intended for use only on Python 2. But strangely, I'm seeing having it installed cause symptoms that are especially bad on Amazon Linux and not as noticeable elsewhere. Test case:

```
$ docker run -it amazonlinux /bin/bash
bash-4.2# yum install -y python36-virtualenv > /dev/null
bash-4.2# virtualenv-3.6 ~/testenv
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /root/testenv/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in /root/testenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
bash-4.2# source ~/testenv/bin/activate
(testenv) bash-4.2# pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from /root/testenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
(testenv) bash-4.2# pip install futures
Collecting futures
  Downloading futures-3.1.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: futures
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for futures ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/ad/79/48/b32521764d59b16fd1bc0ffd
5862f6d3bf770c7d73ea1fb12a
Successfully built futures
Installing collected packages: futures
Successfully installed futures-3.1.1
(testenv) bash-4.2# pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/testenv/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/root/testenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 4
5, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/root/testenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py",
line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/root/testenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 31,
in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/root/testenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 6, i
n <module>
    import compileall
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/compileall.py", line 20, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
  File "/root/testenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/concurrent/futures/__ini
t__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/root/testenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base
.py", line 381
    raise exception_type, self._exception, self._traceback
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Simply having the futures package installed on python 3 on other Linux distributions doesn't seem to cause pip to break, I haven't been able to cause the same symptom on Ubuntu or Fedora yet. What is going on inside a virtualenv on amazonlinux that causes this issue to be especially bad? If I install virtualenv via pip rather than from the amazon linux yum package python36-virtualenv, the problem doesn't manifest there either.

Comment: In case it isn’t clear: `futures` is explicitly not Python 3 compatible. So `pip install` ideally should fail, but if it doesn’t, the package definitely isn’t going to work. The fact that you see the failure a bit sooner on Amazon is, if anything, a good thing, not a problem.

Comment: Meanwhile, my guess at the difference is this: There’s a recent patch (which may make it into 3.7 or the next major setuptools version or something) to use parallel builds more often. Presumably that uses `concurrent.futures`. And presumably Fedora didn’t backport that patch, but Amazon did (despite its author being a Redhat employee who works on Fedora Python packaging). Since you broke `concurrent.futures` by installing in front of it, every parallel build is going to fail, and if most builds default to parallel on Amazon but not on Fedora, you’ll see the problem more often on Amazon.

Comment: Anyway, do you actually need more details on this that you can’t find yourself, or is it enough to know that you cannot install `futures` on 3.x, doing so will break any code that tries to use `concurrent.futures`, and some packages build using `concurrent .futures`?

Comment: This isn't so much an "I need help" question as an "I'm curious what's going on and different between amazonlinux vs elsewhere that makes this break pip" question. Your parallel builds guess sounds like a plausible explanation to me. The specific solution in the project where I was encountering this was to add a python-2-only selector expression on the futures line of my requirements.txt.

Comment: It’s calling `compileall` to build a wheel, and that’s what’s importing your broken `futures` module, so it’s definitely parallel builds. The part that’s a guess is that the difference is that Amazon backported something that Fedora didn’t. The only other possibilities I can think of are that you’re getting all prebuilt wheels for Fedora but not Amazon, or that Amazon has an old `pip` in its virtualenv that wants to update itself. The question is whether it’s worth doing the research to find that out when it really doesn’t matter that much and doesn’t seem all that interesting.